# ListBox CheckBox IsChecked binding using MVVM

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, checkbox, listbox

I'm trying to figure out a way to bind my `CheckBox` `IsChecked` property.  Basically, I have a list of items which the `ListBox` is bound to.  When a user checks the box, a command is invoked and that item is added to a collection.

However, what if I want to programmatically select items in the list?  I would like the `IsChecked` item to be based on whether or not the item exists in a list in the ViewModel.

In other words, if in my viewmodel, I do something like `vm.MySelectedItems.Add(thisItem)`, I would like the `CheckBox` to be `Checked`.

Is this possible and if so, how should I go about it?

Thank you.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <WrapPanel>
            <CheckBox IsChecked={Binding ???} />
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource nameConverter}}" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a ViewModel for each item of your list. In your example: `vm.MySelectedItems.Add(thisItem)` let's assume `thisItem` is of type `ListBoxItemViewModel`. This type should have a property called `IsChecked`, and then in Xaml

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <!-- ViewModel: ListBoxItemViewModel -->
    <DataTemplate>
        <WrapPanel>
            <CheckBox IsChecked={Binding IsChecked} />
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource nameConverter}}" />
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Hope I got your question properly :).

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Anvaka, I thought of that as well, but felt there had to be a better way.  If that's the best way, I'm happy to do it.  Thank you for the response.